# I can connect to ftp and create folder but can't create file or edit

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

I installed ubuntu server 16 on my personal server. I installed vsftpd and accessed ftp in lan with Cyberduck. It works. but when I accessed ftp from outer network. I can create a folder but I can't create file or edit file. It's stuck at downloading until connection timed out.

Comment: Did you look at https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bvsftpd%5D+setup or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39466/vsftpd-553-could-not-create-file-permissions?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I  do everything but  It doesn't work !!!

Answer (score -2):

I  changed to use sftp and It's work!!

Comment: Please don't use answers to make comments. Answers are specifically for providing solutions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment